# reduce repetitive media query head in sass

Tags: html, css, sass

I use mobile first principle for my sass (css), but I found quite a pattern which is quite disturbing.

```
.innerWrap {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    &:first-child {
      margin-right: 20px;
      @media only screen and (min-width: 640px) {
        margin-right: 0;
      }
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 640px) {
      flex: 1;
    }
}
```

Imagine there will be more screen size, there will be

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) 
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) 
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px)
```

everywhere, how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also set a map with all you breakpoints (you can call them as you want) and use it in a mixin.

```
// your variables.scss file

$breakpoints:(
  sm: 640px,
  md: 1200px,
  lg: 1400px,
  xl: 1900px
);


// your mixins.scss file

@mixin min-width($breakpoint){
  @media only screen and (min-width:#{map-get($breakpoints, $breakpoint)}) {
    @content;
  }
}


// your module.scss file

.innerWrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  &:first-child {
    margin-right: 20px;
    @include min-width(sm){
      margin-right: 0;
    }
  }
  @include min-width(sm){
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use @mixin to manage it

https://jsfiddle.net/wyd6pxnh/2/

```
@mixin mediaQuery($point) {
    $mq-device1: "(min-width: 640px)";
    $mq-device2: "(min-width: 1200px)";
    @if $point=="device1" {
      @media #{$mq-device1} {
        @content;
      }
    }
    @else if $point=="device2" {
      @media #{$mq-device2} {
        @content;
      }
    }
  }

  .innerWrap {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    &:first-child {
      margin-right: 20px;
      @include mediaQuery('device1') {
        margin-right: 0;
      }
    }
    @include mediaQuery('device1') {
      flex: 1;
    }
  }
```

#### Output

```
.innerWrap {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .innerWrap:first-child {
    margin-right: 20px;
  }

  @media (min-width: 640px) {
    .innerWrap:first-child {
      margin-right: 0;
    }
  }

  @media (min-width: 640px) {
    .innerWrap {
      flex: 1;
    }
  }
```